# Boltzmann sampling software

Tags: it.information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity, combinatorics

I'm looking for an implementation of Boltzmann sampling for combinatorial structures.

Recent paper in the area for context:

http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/74/77/09/PDF/NonRedundantGeneration-TCS-2010.pdf

Any good packages out there that don't rely on Maple?